# "On/off problem" resources

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, references, binomial-distribution, profile-likelihood

I need to study in depth the on/off problem with different approaches: frequentist, bayesian - frequentist hybrid, profile likelihood.

The on/off problem is a counting experiment where you observe $n_{on}$ events when the source is "on" in the time $T_{on}$ and $n_{off}$ events when the source is "off" in time $T_{off}$ and you want to make inferences about the source power (the simpler case power > 0 ?)

Do you know some good books?

Some references on the problem:

- [Tucker 2008](http://cern.ch/phystat-lhc/2008-001.pdf#page=48)
- [Cousins Linemann & Tucker 2008](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168900208010255)
- [Cranmer 2011](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=kyle%20cranmer%20romania%20summer%20school&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Findico.cern.ch%2FgetFile.py%2Faccess%3FcontribId%3D19%26resId%3D1%26materialId%3Dslides%26confId%3D117033&ei=SJzCTvTZCbTa4QSq84yXDQ&usg=AFQjCNGQMcP9eL2qfm-UBGVO3b64TRyWoQ&sig2=wKodUpkUo5oOOQrxs05sXQ&cad=rja) (page 36)

Comment: Something's missing here: because there's no stated connection between "power" (whatever that might be) and the counts, the problem seems identical to comparing two independent Binomial observations.  How is it intended to be different?  Can you supply a reference or link?

Comment: Based on your edit and a review of the first two links, "power" is expected count per unit time for a Poisson process.  The problem is to test the hypothesis of equal power during both intervals against a one-sided alternative of greater power during the "on" interval.  I wonder what you are hoping to find in books that has not already appeared in your references?

Comment: @whuber: I need a more didactic approach, with example and so on

Comment: If you are still interested, maybe look into Poisson regression?